# Text file Vs SQL?

Tags: sql, text

I am using a simple text file to store filenames and their hashvalues; which is later read to search a particular file. Should I go for SQL for such simple task ?

Comment: We need more information. How will it make your system better?

Comment: What are you using the file for? What are you using to extract the data?

Comment: Google is your friend my friend.

Comment: Data volume? Updated? Deletes? Concurrent access? Search logic?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your need and operations.
If you need simple operation like read and write ( updates and deletion are difficult than DB) considering with a very low volume data sizes it's ok to go that way (not recommending).

Relational Databases are always better than normal file systems because of their rows and tuples structure, suitable for data manipulation operations.

If your need are simple use a json or XML structures. They are way better than raw text files

Comment: Thanks for suggesting JSON.